# Half angle formulas

Tags: trigonometry

Say I have the trig identity

$$
\tan \frac{\theta}{2}  = \frac{ 1 - \cos \theta }{ \sin \theta  }
$$

And you have the 3,4,5 triangle:

[image]

taking the angle $\theta$ as marked, why can't we just say

$$
\tan \frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{ 1.5 }{ 4 }

= \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }
$$

(Like, if you half $\theta$, then the opposite side length is seen as half, right?)

But this doesn't work or check out with the identity:

$$
\tan \frac{\theta}{2}  = \frac{ 1 - \frac{4}{5} }{ \frac{3}{5}  }

= \frac{ \frac{1}{5} }{ \frac{3}{5}  }

= \frac{1}{3}
$$

Comment: "(Like, if you halve θ, then the opposite side length is seen as half, right?)" - nope. If you draw a line at an angle θ/2 from the "4" leg, it won't intersect the "3" leg at its midpoint.

Comment: Imagine the case where $\theta$ is a large acute angle, like $89^\circ$.  Then $\tan\theta$ is big, but $\tan\frac{\theta}{2}<1$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, if you half an angle, it will divide the opposite side proportionally to the two other sides. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem )

In your case, 3 would be divided into parts $4/3$ and $5/3$.

So you get $\tan \theta/2=(4/3)/4= 1/3$. Everything works out fine.